# Overloading the Subscript[] operator in C++ to set the size of a class(quantifier).

Tags: c++, overloading, subscript-operator

Good day guys.

I have the following struct and class,

```
template <class T>
struct Node
{
    T DataMember;
    Node* Next;
};

template <class T>
class NCA
{
    public:
        NCA();
        ~NCA();
        void push(T);
        T pop();
        void print();
        void Clear();
    private:
        Node<T>* Head;
        void* operator new(unsigned int);
};
```

I would like to instantiate the class with a size

ie. NCA[30] as one would any array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the compiler were to allow you to use brackets in your object constructor, how would it know whether you were trying to make an `NCA` of size 30 or an array of 30 `NCA` objects? C++ does not allow you to override the bracket syntax, except as an operator once you already have an object.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. But, you can do something almost like that: initialize it with parenthesis, but not brackets:

```
NCA<int> myList(30);
```

Implement it like so:

```
template <class T>
class NCA
{
  ...
  public:
    explicit NCA(std::size_t count);
  ...
 };

template <class T>
NCA<T>::NCA(std::size_t count) {
  ... allocate Head, &c ...
  while(count--)
    push(T());
}
```

Comment: The constructor should be `explicit` to avoid automatic conversion of `size_t` to `NCA`.

Answer (score 3):

That's not quite how `operator[]` works.

When you write `NCA[30]` you're writing `type[30]`, where as to use `operator[]` you need an *instance*:

```
NCA inst;
inst[30];
```

What you can do though is use an integer template parameter to specify the size, e.g.:

```
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t N>
class NCA {
  char bytes[N];
};

int main() {
  NCA<1024> instance;
}
```

Comment: To Everyone: I apologize - awoodland is absolutely right - i meant 

        NCA nca[30]
then use nca

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You can only use the ctor to do it like:

```
NCA n(30);
```

Comment: Thank you all - sigh it saddens my heart. I really wanted to do this.... I'll then just have to take compiler construction in Honours and then fix this little bug

:)